# Get last X values from a table starting from the current row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to make a formula to retrieve a range of cells inmediate up of the current one.

For example, in this table the **SUM 5** column has to calculate the `SUM` for the last 5 values (including the same cell).

[image: Table example]

I tried with `OFFSET` but I don't seem to find the right approach.

Would you mind pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUM(OFFSET(B2,,,-MIN(5,MATCH(B2,B:B,0))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or not use `INDIRECT()` at all.

Use `=SUM($B2:$B6)` for the formula in D6, then copy down. It will always be the five cells in column B starting in the cell's row and counting upward four more cells. So B3:B7, B4:B8, B5:B9, and so on down the column.

If you have a normal situation, it doesn't really matter except for being easier to understand. If you have a huge number of rows to work with, it will likely make a visible difference in calculation time.

And it's very easy for anyone looking under the hood to understand and be sure it's doing what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

Excels INDIRECT formula will allow you to designate the row and column in the formula. If you add the column in quotes & use the ROW formula and subtract 4 it should provide what you are looking for. Please find an example below.

[image]

Hopefully this helps,

Brad

Comment: You could also use one formula for all the rows instead of a different formula at the beginning. This formula goes in `D2` and gets copied down: `=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&MAX(2,ROW()-4)):B2)`